# Gitab CI : rules with changes to a dir/path

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to add this logic in my CI :

- don't add job to pipeline on `merge_request_events` or when merge request target branch is protected and when changes are made to any file in the `e2e` directory
- add job when the branch to which I'm merging to is one of the following  `dev`, `test` or `demo`
- don't add job to pipeline in any other case.

Here are my rules

```
.ci-rules:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_PROTECTED == "true"'
      changes: 
        - "e2e/**/*"
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "dev" || $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "test" || $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "demo"'
      when: always
    - when: never


build:
  rules:
    - !reference [.ci-rules, rules]
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "do something"
  allow_failure: false
```

Issue:
When I make changes to files in `e2e` directory only the job is still added to the pipeline.

I'd appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with the following

```
.ci-rules:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "dev" || $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "test" || $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "demo"'
      changes: 
        - "e2e/**/*"
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "dev" || $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "test" || $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "demo"'
      when: always
    - when: never
```